# NetMQ Publish Subscribe with Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Example

Tags: c#, zeromq, multicastsocket, netmq

I have been trying to use NetMQ using IP Multicasting ("PGM").  I can successfully send and receive messages to/from the publisher and subscriber.  However, I can't see that it is actually using MSMQ, which is installed along with its Multicasting Support (see https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/#pgm).  Unfortunately, there are no good NetMQ examples that specifically target MSMQ.

My biggest concern is that with MSMQ, you typically define a Private Queue.  However, I don't see in any example how you reference the queue.  Has anyone ever tried this?  Would you have any sample code?

Comment: have you been able to get anywhere on this?  I am looking at NetMQ to do the same sort of thing....

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Although I'll admin that I haven't been trying to resolve it since I wrote this original post.  NetMQ seems to work okay, but documentation for real-world is lacking.  I still am hopeful someone can help answer and provide us with the steps to having this running alongside of MSMQ.

Comment: PGM actually has nothing to do with MSMQ queues. It is a reliable multicast protocol, the only relation to MSMQ is that on Windows the MSMQ stack implemented the protocol.

Comment: Thanks, somdoron.  I agree that pgm is a standard multicast protocol and on Windows, the only way to use it is through MSMQ.  I was trying to figure out if guaranteed delivery could be done using NetMQ -> pgm -> MSMQ.  I'm not sure if it can be done now.  I just stumbled upon this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/reliable-multicast-programming--pgm-